# Counting the word frequency after stemming the words

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Assume that I have the following string:

```
"present present present presenting presentation do  do doing "
```

And I'm counting the words inside the string according to their frequency in descending order:

```
I'm using GroupBy count 
present    3
do         2
doing      1
presenting 1
presentation 1
```

Then, I'm stemming the words:

```
using array [ , ] or any other structure

present  3
do       2
do       1
present  1
present  1
```

Finally, I want to recount the words into dictionary. So that the output should be:

```
present 5
do      3
```

Can anyone help please??. thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem? You seem to indicate you understand how to perform a count, so once you stem, just do it again. Is it actually stemming that's the issue?

Comment: I think the question should be edited to.. Can you recommended a stemming library?

Comment: @Qaesar after you stem the words, group again, but sum the counts of the previous groups.

Comment: phoog, great, that what I want. But how ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Using List instead of Dictionary to allow keys multiplicity:
            List> words = new List< KeyValuePair>();

```
        string text = "present present present presenting presentation do  do doing";
        var ws = text.Split(' ');

        //Passing the words into the list:
        words = (from w in ws
                 group w by w into wsGroups
                 select new KeyValuePair<string, int>(
                     wsGroups.Key, ws.Count()
                     )
                 ).ToList<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

        //Ordering:
        words.OrderBy(w => w.Value);

        //Stemming the words:
        words = (from w in words
                 select new KeyValuePair<string, int>
                     (
                         stemword(w.Key),
                         w.Value
                     )).ToList<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

        //Sorting and put into Dictionary:
        var wordsRef = (from w in words
                        group w by w.Key into groups
                        select new
                        {
                            count = groups.Count(),
                            word = groups.Key
                        }).ToDictionary(w => w.word, w => w.count);
```

Comment: Exsaliver, great. But if I have a procedure named stemword(word) which returns the stem of each word, where I have to locate it in your code if I want to stem the word after the first grouping??

Comment: And your problem is that you can't enter two same key into dictionary or what?

Comment: yes, I can't enter two same key into dictionary after running the stemmer. Just look at the example please.

Comment: Just one thing more, if my input is a string of words, how to group the words to get the List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> which contains for example ("present", 3) ..........and son on ??

Answer (score 0):

LINQ GroupBy or Aggregate are good methods to compute such counts.

If you want to do it by hand... It looks like you want to have 2 sets of results: one of non-stemmed words, another stemmed:

```
void incrementCount(Dictionary<string, int> counts, string word)
{
  if (counts.Contains(word))
  {
    counts[word]++;
  }
  else
  {
    counts.Add(word, 0);
  }
}

var stemmedCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var nonStemmedCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach(word in words)
{
  incrementCount(stemmedCount, Stem(word));
  incrementCount(nonStemmedCount, word);
}
```

Comment: Alexei, I want to group the words first, then I conduct the stemmer. After the stemmer, there are some words will be duplicated again. How  I sum the counts of duplicated words with previous ?

Comment: @Qaesar, I don't get what you want. Please write code in your question so it is possible to figure out what data structure you have and what portion of counting causes problems.

Comment: Ok, let we have an array (2D)  which contains: present 3 , present 1 , do 2 , do 1 . how i recount them again. so that the output will be : present 4 , do 3 ????

Comment: @Qaesar, Please edit your question with code you have. It is very hard to understand what you have problem with without actual code.